# Calculate Moving Time

Tags: gps, php

I am wondering how web apps like Garmin connect or Strava calculate a "moving time" from a gps track.

For example I might record a GPS track on my Garmin GPS that has an elapsed time of 5:34:26 but they calculate the moving time as 2:33:39.

I can't seem to find an discussion or examples on how this is done, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong things.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/garmin-moving-time

Comment: Intuitive : Only when coordinates change.

Comment: Garmin link doesn't work.